# datatables + adding a filter per column

Tags: filter, datatables

How do I get the search/filter to work per column?

I am making small steps in building, and constantly adding to my data table, which is pretty dynamic at this stage. It basically builds a datatable based on the dat that is fed into it. I have now added the footer to act as a search/filter, but unfortunately this is where I have become stuck. I cannot get the filer part to work. Advice greatly appreciated.

here is my sample data tables that I am working on http://live.datatables.net/qociwesi/2/edit

It basically has dTableControl object that builds by table.

To build my table I need to call loadDataFromSocket which does the following:

```
//then I have this function for loading my data and creating my tables
//file is an array of objects
//formatFunc is a function that formats the data in the data table, and is stored in options for passing to the dTableControl for formatting the datatable - not using this in this example
//ch gets the keys from file[0] which will be the channel headers
//then I add the headers
//then I add the footers
//then I create the table
//then i build the rows using the correct values from file
//then I draw and this then draws all the row that were built
//now the tricky part of applying the search to each columns
```

So i have got this far but the search per column is not working. How do I get the search/filter to wrok per column?

Note this is a very basic working example that I have been working off: http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/t12w3a65/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `t1.oTable` to access DataTables API, see [updated example](http://live.datatables.net/qociwesi/4) for demonstration.

Please compare your code with jsFiddle in your question, notice its simplicity and consider rewriting your code.

Comment: tks, can you elaborate more on why I should rewrite. the jsfiddle example is a static table that datatables works on whereas my example is dynamic and is able to draw what is given to it. And this is probs why it is more complicated. Your response would be appreciated as I am just a novice!!

Comment: @HattrickNZ, although your code allows you to construct the table dynamically, I think your code is unnecessary complex. This will lead to errors and problems with maintenance in future. Code complexity is most likely the reason why you mistakenly used `t1` instead of `t1.oTable`.

Comment: tks but more specifically is `dTableControl` object the complicated part or the `loadDataFromSocket ` function that builds the datatable? or is it a combination? tks for the advice I will see how i can simplify it.